# db2 not able to load output of uniq command in linux

Tags: bash, shell, db2

I have a file with below data:

```
<row num="1">
   <INN>20003943
   </INN>
</row>

<row num="2">
   <INN>20003943
   </INN>
</row>

<row num="3">
  <INN>20003943
  </INN>
 </row>
```

Notice that INN value is always same: 20003943. So uniq must return single value always which should go into INN column.

I am having the below command to get that INN value:

```
INN=$(grep "<INN>" "$file" |cut -f2 -d'>'|uniq)
```

INN variable is getting correct value I want. I tested by doing echo $INN.

I have a db2 table with below schema:

```
create table Data ( INN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL )
```

Now I have a below db2 insert command:

```
db2 -v "INSERT INTO Data(INN, ID) values ('"$INN"','"$ID"')"
```

When I run it I see only ID column. INN column is empty. echo statement right above insert command prints INN value properly.

This is the log for db2 insert command:

```
 ','4')ta(INN,ID) values ('20003943
  DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Above log looks suspicious.. wondering if there is some new line char or some other thing

Second time I did :

```
  INN=201090909
```

and then I did db2 insert again:

```
   db2 "INSERT INTO Data(INN, ID) values ('"$INN"','"$ID"')"
```

Now I see two columns populated.

Wondering if it has to do with some data type of output returned by grep command.

**UPDATE**

When i did

```
 db2 "select * from Data" INN column appeared empty
```

but when i did

```
 db2 "select substr(INN,1,10),ID from Data" i see the INN column populated
```

Comment: just because $IN has the correct value, doesn't mean you're using it correctly in your query. You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and `IN` is a reserved word as well. you may want to check if it needs to be delimited.

Comment: I renamed the variable to INN and still same result.

Comment: did you tell db2 which database you're dealing with? all you've got there is the name of a table, which isn't of much use.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: Can you explain your logic for using quotes the way you did? Specifically around the values being inserted.

Comment: Hi Matt.. no logic... I tried several ways like '$INN', $INN, '"$INN"'. Both '$INN and '"$INN"' worked fine.

Comment: Can you please provide a couple of lines from `$file`?  Otherwise everyone is just guessing at what the possible problem is.

Comment: Running `db2 -v` instead of just `db2` will show you what the DB2 CLP thinks you're passing in. Other than that, it would help if you provided more detail about your input file format and all the steps you're taking to prepare the data in $INN for insertion (i.e. stripping off the trailing `</INN` if it exists, handling potentially multiple values returned by `uniq`, etc.)

Comment: I added the file which grep command uses

Comment: @FredSobotka if you see my grep command... input of grep is passed to cut to get only the value of INN. and as I said there are no multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim off any leading whitespace before passing the variables into the DB2 CLP. Until you confirm everything is working properly, leave the verbose option enabled on the DB2 CLP.

```
INN=`echo $INN`
ID=`echo $ID`
db2 -v "INSERT INTO data( inn, id ) VALUES('$INN', '$ID')"
```

Comment: tried your suggestion .. no luck. I updated my question. Please check

Comment: I changed the grep command as below: $(grep -m1 "<INN>" "$file" |cut -f2 -d'>'|tr -d '\040\011\012\015') and it works. I stripped off all white spaces, tabs, newlines using above tr command.